# angular js does not recognize variables in scope

Tags: django, scope, angularjs

I am new to `angularjs` infact this is the first time I am using `angularjs` in one of my applications. The application is developed using django. But what I am trying at the moment is not related to django (i guess), I have a very simple template as follows:

```
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" lang="en" ng-app"><head>
    <title>Testing Angular</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/application.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" »="" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/messages.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/marketing/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/marketing/controllers.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" ng-controller="UserListControl" class="ng-scope">
        [[ users.length ]]
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and following is the content for `app.js` and `controllers.js` respectively.

#### app.js

```
'use strict';

var newApp = angular.module('newApp', []) 
    .config(function($interpolateProvider){
        // To prevent the conflict of `{{` and `}}` symbols
        // between django templating and angular templating we need
        // to use different symbols for angular.
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    });
```

#### controllers.js

```
function UserListControl($scope) {
    $scope.users = [   
        {   
            'name' : 'John Doe',
            'type' : 'Platinum',
        },  
        {   
            'name' : 'Matt Hill',
            'type' : 'Gold',
        }   
    ];  
}
```

but the template simply renders `[[ users.length ]]` instead of actually rendering the length.

I also tried the `ngRepeat` directive as follows:

```
<p ng-repeat="user in users">
    <p>[[user.name]], ([[user.type]])</p>
<p>
```

and

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]"><td>[[ i ]]</td></tr>
```

the first `ng-repeat` directive renders:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: usr in users -->
<p ng-repeat="usr in users" class="ng-scope">
        </p>
<p ng-repeat="usr in users" class="ng-scope">
        </p>
<p><a href="#"></a>()</p>
<p></p>
```

and the second one renders:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] -->
<tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]" class="ng-scope"><td>[[ i ]]</td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]" class="ng-scope"><td>[[ i ]]</td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]" class="ng-scope"><td>[[ i ]]</td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]" class="ng-scope"><td>[[ i ]]</td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]" class="ng-scope"><td>[[ i ]]</td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]" class="ng-scope"><td>[[ i ]]</td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]" class="ng-scope"><td>[[ i ]]</td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]" class="ng-scope"><td>[[ i ]]</td></tr>
```

why is it not able to recognize the variables ? what am i doing wrong ?

#### PS:

There are no errors in the console.

- Angular Version: 1.0.0
- Django Version: 1.4
- Web Browser: Google Chrome 24.0.1312.68
- Operating System: Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Out of curiosity: has it ever worked with `{{}}`? What happens if you change your code - just for testing purposes?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen, If i remove the `$.interpolateProvider` code and use the default curly braces, nothing is rendered, just the HTML elements are with no values at all. And if i try using other symbols it simply renders it as text instead of rendering varibale values. i am confused phew.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you change the attribute in your `html` tag to `ng-app="newApp"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your bootstrapping on the HTML element, the ng-app attribute should look like this:

```
ng-app="newApp"
```

That way angular will know to use the module you've defined in your app.js. I just tried it with your code, and the interpolateProvider changes work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i did updated it to use the app name, but it still didn't make a difference.

Comment: Could you paste in your updated code? It's possible there's another typo somewhere. Also see the answer below about the malformed HTML for your repeater; it should just be <p ng-repeat="user in users"[[user.name]], ([[user.type]])</p>.

Comment: moving the ngApp directive to another element did the trick :P

Answer (score 1):

Add an ng-app="newApp", try moving your angular script tag to the bottom of your html body and fix the closing p tag in the first user repeater.

```
<div ng-app="newApp">
<div id="content" ng-controller="UserListControl" class="ng-scope">
        [[ users.length ]]

        <p ng-repeat="user in users">[[user.name]], ([[user.type]])</p>
</div>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

See the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwanga/VLRVU/